# Can I fly with glass photographic filters in my hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, legal, airport-security, photography

I'd like to take my glass photographic filters with me on a flight. These are square, made of glass, fragile, and have sharpish edges like in the photo below:

[image: Glass photographic filters]

Are glass filters allowed in hand-luggage? Will they be considered as sharps?

Ideally I'd like to know about both EU and US regulations.

Comment: Don't they come in a box with padded separators ? Maybe try sealing the box before going ?

Comment: Sealed box in hand-held luggage will surely be opened by custom agents.
I'd ask the airline you will be taking (and/or TSA if flying in USA)

Comment: good question !

Comment: Where and with which air line? Both national, official regulations, but also air line restrictions might prohibit this in carry-on luggage, but it both depends on where you are flying and with which air line.

Comment: photographers have only been doing just that for decades, why the heck would you think it's not allowed?

Comment: @jwenting Genuine curiosity? New tighter security regulations? What's the purpose of your aggressive comment?

Answer (score 3):

These are not considered as "sharps"<sup>1</sup>, but my recommendation is to carry them in a carrying case (something like [this item from Nisi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017GZVUQE)):

[image: nisi carrying case (amazon)]

I would not risk it in checked baggage unless you put them in a Pelican case or something extremely robust.

Source - sadly, first hand experience with checked in photography equipment, even though it was in its original box AND surrounded by packing foam.

<sup>1</sup> - as long as you don't run into the same TSA agent as [this poor fellow](https://fstoppers.com/news/tsa-confiscates-blower-because-it-could-fly-missile-8415).

Comment: You put them in your carry-on and security said nothing?

Comment: *If* the glass filters were prohibited in carry-on luggage, it would of course be irrelevant if they are carried in a protective case or not.

Comment: In the UK, certainly, these go through just fine in a case - airport security seems to finally understand photographer's kit.

Comment: While I own no such square filters I have a holder of the round screw-on type, it's been through airport security and never drawn the slightest interest.